# Formatting data to JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, python-2.7

I'm getting data from PostgreSQL using python

```
import psycopg2
import json

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="testdb", user="openpg", password="openpgpwd", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
print "Opened database successfully"

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT id, name, address, salary  from COMPANY")
rows = cur.fetchall() 

print "Operation done successfully";
```

Then i try to format this data to JSON format: with the following command:

```
result = json.dumps(rows)

for row in result:
   print row
```

but i get each caracteres of the ID, Name, address, ... in a separate row:

for example : name= abc 
when execute the script i get:

a

b

c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result (`rows`) is a string (that's what `json.dumps()` returns). That's why when you iterate thru rows, you are iterating and printing each character.

just do `print rows` instead

Answer (score 0):

`json.dumps()` returns a string, so iterating over returns each character.

To get a stream, use `json.dump()`